# Angular 2 does not detect changes for @HostBinding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, drag-and-drop

I use `@HostBinding` to set a class together with Chrome's Drag and Drop API like this:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[sortable-article]' })
export class SortableArticleComponent {

    @HostBinding('class.dragged-element')
    isDraggedArticle: boolean = false;

    constructor(elRef: ElementRef, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private appRef: ApplicationRef, private dndService: ArticleDndService) {
        this.el = elRef.nativeElement;
        Observable.fromEvent(this.el, 'dragstart').subscribe(e => this.onDragStart(<DragEvent> e));
        Observable.fromEvent(this.el, 'drop').subscribe(e => this.onDrop(<DragEvent> e));
    }

    onDragStart(event: DragEvent) {
        this.isDraggedArticle = true;
    }

    onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.isDraggedArticle = false;
    }
}
```

What happens is that more times then not, the `isDraggedArticle` class does not get removed from the element and I don't know why. I tried adding

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
this.appRef.tick();
```

to the onDrop method (where `ref` is a `ChangeDetectorRef` and `appRef` is an `ApplicationRef`), but it does not help.

Comment: So your onDrop method is called at right time and isDraggedArticle doesn't change?

Comment: Yes, good point, but I can confirm that because actually more stuff happens in onDrop that gets actually executed.

Comment: For me your code is right. No changes if you initialize isDraggedArticle in constructor? @HostBinding('class.dragged-element')
    isDraggedArticle: boolean;
constructor(){this.isDraggedArticle = false}

Comment: No, does not work either :(

Comment: Ok, I am interested in this topic. I am not at home but I am gonna do a try more later and see If we can have some conclusions. For now, I ve been reading a little about and examples I have seen similar to your scenario are doing event.preventDefault() after the asignation. I mean 
this.isDraggedArticle = false;
event.preventDefault();
At begining had no sense for me but looking at your error I thought It could apply default state as true if the "execution" is being onDragStart and then it set the value as true without regard your preventDefault() being before the assignation.I dont know

Comment: What I think it is caused because synchronism. But I am far from knowing what really happens. And I would like.

Comment: Hey @Sam I found the solution! See my own answer for details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich think I found the solution to the problem: The `drop` event is not triggered on the item that has been dragged but is triggered on the item that is dropped onto. This means instead of setting `this.isDraggedArticle = false` in the drop callback, I need to do it in the `dragend` callback:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[sortable-article]' })
export class SortableArticleComponent {

    @HostBinding('class.dragged-element')
    isDraggedArticle: boolean = false;

    constructor(elRef: ElementRef, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private appRef: ApplicationRef, private dndService: ArticleDndService) {
        this.el = elRef.nativeElement;
        Observable.fromEvent(this.el, 'dragstart').subscribe(e => this.onDragStart(<DragEvent> e));
        Observable.fromEvent(this.el, 'dragend').subscribe(e => this.onDragEnd(<DragEvent> e));
    }

    onDragStart(event: DragEvent) {
        this.isDraggedArticle = true;
    }

    onDragEnd(event: DragEvent) {
        this.isDraggedArticle = false;
    }
}
```